# Is there an app that can scan all running processes in windows and tell which ones are not well-known?

Tags: windows-10, security, antivirus

I am wondering if I can scan my running processes/apps in windows and find out which ones are not well-known.

A list of unknown running processes/apps should be listed.

Note: the app should NOT turn off Microsoft Defender. Most of anti-virus apps will turn off Microsoft Defender protection after its installation. So I have to make clear on this point.

PS: in another word, I would like to find a whitelist scanner instead of blacklist virus scanner.

Comment: What do you mean by "**well-known**"?

Comment: @slybloty thanks a lot for your reply. Sorry that I am not a native English speaker and I am not sure if **well-known** is the right word or not. I mean apps (exe processes) that are famous and known by others. Thus, those processes should be safe processes (non-virus). I want to use this way to make sure my windows OS is secure. I don't really care how good the well-known exe list is. As long as the scanner can tell me what exe processes it can NOT recognize, it will be best to me. I like white list scanner, instead of blacklist scanner. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite hard to tell which process should be running and which shouldn't. Even some Microsoft Windows programs will only run seldomly. But there's one easy thing to check: whether the application's digital signature is valid or not. The tool I use for this is:

### Microsoft SysInternals [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

0. Run the tool as administrator in order to see all processes. This step is optional. If you don't or can't run as administrator, your results may be incomplete

   [image: Show details for all processes]
1. click on the "Process" column until it is sorted by name (to get rid of the tree-view).

   [image: Sort by name]
2. Enable "Verify image signatures" in the options

   [image: Verify image signatures]
3. This will show a new column where you can check whether the application's digital signature could be verified (or not)

   [image: Verified signature]
4. You can now google for the processes that do not have a digital signature. Most suspect are applications that have the name of a large company (e.g. Microsoft) but no digital certificate. A lot of Open Source software does not come with digital signatures, unfortunately.
5. If you like, you can also check for results at VirusTotal.

   [image: VirusTotal check]
6. Sort the list by the VirusTotal result. The worst numbers on my system are Brother printer drivers (no digital signature and some false positives)

   [image: VirusTotal results]

As for your requirements:

- it works on Windows 10 (the screenshots have been taken on Windows 10)
- it will not turn off Windows Defender
- on top of that it's gratis, so you've got nothing to lose

Answer (score 1):

If you liked Process Explorer, I may suggest another tool on top, which complements Process Explorer

### Microsoft SysInternals [AutoRuns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

Process Explorer only shows and checks processes that are currently running. But: what will your PC run in the future? Autoruns checks exactly that: programs that might run at startup, might run when you play a video etc.

0. Run as administrator, if you can. Otherwise the results may be incomplete.

   [image: Run as administrator]
1. In the scan options, activate at least the second option (verify code signatures). I also like to activate the VirusTotal option.

   [image: Scan options]

   [image: options to be activated]
2. To get a better overview of the dangerous items, you can hide Windows items, Microsoft items (probably includes Office etc. in addition to Windows) and those items for which VirusTotal says 0

   [image: Hide options]

As for your requirements:

- it works on Windows 10 (the screenshots have been taken on Windows 10)
- it will not turn off Windows Defender
- on top of that it's gratis, so you've got nothing to lose